# Reposition widgets at runtime using drag and drop

Tags: gtkmm

Is it possible to move widgets around in its container such as *Gtk::Box* or *Gtk::Grid* using drag and drop? I believe *Gtk::List* allows reordering of rows by click-drag-drop. However I could not find any documentation related to the implementation. The concept of drag and drop appears to be for exchanging data between widgets rather than modifying layout. Is this even supported natively?

I am using *gtkmm-3.0*.

Comment: If its done in `Gtk::List`, it means the concept of drag and dropping for modifying layouts exists in gtk/gtkmm. However, it is more than possible that no clear documentation exist on the topic (as it is often the case with gtk/gtkmm). My best bet would be to look at Inkspace, find some drag and dropping that changes the layout (if any) and go inspect the code...

Comment: You can write a GTK widget where this is possible, but one is not included among the standard GTK widgets.